# Selecting specific row in attribute table using ArcPy (without iterating through whole table)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, update

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and have assumed until now that it is possible to select a specific row in an attribute table. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. The only available methods seem to be to return a search or update cursor, and to iterate through each row in the table.

Is there really no way to select only the desired row?

What I am trying to do is to select a target row - e.g. 50423 - and then to update a field for that row. I'd hate to iterate through the entire table of millions of records.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In arcpy, When you implement the [Search Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000) or [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) you have the option of using the **where_clause** parameter, which will allow you to select a specific row based on a field value (e.g. row ID).

[This help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002t000000) will show you how to build an appropriate SQL query for selecting a specific row.