# Change specific rows in attribute table using Arcpy in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, cursor

I need to change values in field "name1" (string field) in specific rows: 70-72 into "no land use" value. I search Arcpy code to do it.

i red [How to select specific row in attribute table using ArcPy (without iterating through whole table)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82641/how-to-select-specific-row-in-attribute-table-using-arcpy-without-iterating-thr) but didn't understand what shoud i do.

I using this code:

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"G:\PROJECTS\herzel138\gis\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb\digum2"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, ["name1"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row == 70 and row ==71 and row ==72:
            row[0] = 'no land use'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            print "Processing complete"
        else:
            print 'nothing founded'
```

[image]

but i get no result:

[image]

Comment: name1 field type text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check the value of the OBJECTID field, not the `row` object:

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"G:\PROJECTS\herzel138\gis\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb\digum2"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, ["name1", "OID@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in (70, 71, 72):
            row[0] = 'no land use'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            print """Updated row {}""".format(row[1])
```

The OID@ token refers to the OBJECTID field, no matter how it's called (this may vary depending on the dataset format - file gdb, shapefile, enterprise gdb...). See the [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the answer provided you dont need to iterate over every row in the table. In your case you could specify a where_clause in the cursor to only iterate over OIDs 70-72 and then update them without an if statement.

```
import arcpy
lyrName = r"G:\PROJECTS\herzel138\gis\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb\digum2"
sql = """{0} IN (70,71,72)""".format(arcpy.Describe(lyrName).OIDFieldName)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table=lyrName, field_names='name1', where_clause=sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]='no land use'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This is indeed more efficient/elegant :) But unless there are at least 100 000s of rows the performance gain will not be noticeable I think

Comment: I agree, I usually dont bother using a where_clause since the cursor is so fast anyway

Comment: If there is an index on **1000** or more rows, `where_clause` use will ***always*** be noticeably faster. Constraining the query to return only the required rows is always best practice.