# Changing different multi values based on the FID field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, multi-values

Continually to

[Changing 1000 values in attribute table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266924/changing-1000-values-in-attribute-table-using-arcpy)

[Change specific rows in attribute table using Arcpy in ArcGIS 10.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266900/change-specific-rows-in-attribute-table-using-arcpy-in-arcgis-10-3)

I try to change 850 different values in attribute table of point layer into value "red use" (the total features in this layer is 1300).

I need to change FID start from 300 til FID 1150 and using this code:

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\point1.shp"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, ["name", "FID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in (0, 1, 2):
            row[0] = 'no land use'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            print """Updated row {}""".format(row[1])
```

Line number 6 is the rows that should be changed. I understand that row

```
 if row[1] in (0, 1, 2):
```

should be change- but i don't how.
How can i changed those 850 row with python code, based on FID field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `OID@` token available with [data access cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). It can be used in place of the FID field name for the feature class.

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\point1.shp"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, ["name", "OID@"]) as cursor:
    for name, oid in cursor:
        if oid >= 300 and oid < 1150:
            row = ("no land use", oid)
            curs.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: Emil, your code works after i changed the last row into: cursor.updateRow (row)    thanks.